# Getting Error while deploying a next.js project on netlify. How to resolve that?

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, node-modules, netlify

I am trying to deploy a next.js project on netlify by selecting a git repo. But every time I am deploying it, gives me error. I tried removing package-lock.json file as well as downgrading the version of react and react-dom. But still I am getting this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBP1I.png)

Also I tried Using  command

```
npm install -g npm@latest  & npm audit fix
```

But nothing works. What should I do now to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You should change your build command to `CI=false npm run build`. This will tell netlify to not treat warnings as errors. For more info check netlify forum:

https://answers.netlify.com/t/treating-warnings-as-errors-because-process-env-ci-true/81742

Comment: Thanks for telling. But I just changes react-reveal library to react-awesome-reveal library and this solves my problem without doing anything else.